# MySQL datetime vs timestamp and highcharts

Tags: mysql, datetime, highcharts, timestamp

I have been using highcharts for datetime-based charts and it needs a timestamp to make the chart.

In my DB I have a DATETIME column and I convert to timestamp when I do the select:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(`datetime`, '+00:00', @@session.time_zone)) * 1000 AS datetime
```

I have a lot of rows and I think that select may be slow. Should I store the dates as timestamp instead of datetime?

Comment: The best way to find out is to test it.